# Random place change in row with restrictions

Tags: text-processing

How could I randomly change places of characters in a text file, with some probability (say 10%)?

file:

```
1  34567
2  12356
3  16987
```

outcome:

```
1  35674
2  12653
3  61987
```

Comment: You might want to clarify (by [editing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/241090/edit) your question) what the rest of the requirements are. Only values in the second column? What are the valid replacement values (1 through 9? 0? deletion? swapping?)

Answer (score 0):

Save the following script to `scramble.sh`:

```
posts=""
arrlen=0
rempos=0

cat | while read procl
  do for i in `seq 0 $((${#procl}-1))`
       do let arrlen=$arrlen+1
       done
     # scramble characters
     posts=""
     for i in `seq 0 $((${#procl}-1))`
       do if [ $((RANDOM%5)) -eq 1 ]
             then rempos=$((RANDOM%arrlen))
             else rempos=0
          fi
          posts+=${procl:$rempos:1}
          procl="${procl:0:$((rempos))}${procl:$((rempos+1)):$((arrlen-rempos-1))}"
          let arrlen=$arrlen-1
       done
      echo "$posts"
  done
```

Then use it like this:

```
$ cat (file name) | bash scramble.sh
```

e.g.

```
$ cat test.txt | bash scramble.sh
36475
15236
81679
```

And if you want to save the result to a file do:

```
$ cat (file name) | bash scramble.sh > (new file name)
```

Comment: @SANDO: It would be nice if you could take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Nope, it is not working good, it replace more than 5% digits. It can be better if replaced randomly 5% of digits with "A"